# TypeScript/RXJS - lastValueFrom unexpected behaviour

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am a beginner with rxjs and was testing the subscribe function. I decided to subscribe to the observable itself when it was emitting values. When `lastValueFrom(x1$);` is placed in the same place or commented out, no output is displayed on console. It is expected in my opinion because I shouldn't subscribe there (I do appreciate a logical explanation because I don't know why). However, when placing `lastValueFrom(x1$);` *after* initializing the observable, the code executes more than 1000 times and then stops. I am not sure why not what is going on. Here is the snippet:

```js
import { Observable,  lastValueFrom} from "rxjs";

class LastValueFromExample {
    constructor() {
        let x1$: Observable<number>;
        console.log("===Start===");
        let i = 0;
        x1$ = new Observable((channel) => {
            i++;
            channel.next(Math.random());
            x1$.subscribe((x) => { console.log(`${i} value: ${x}`); });//subscribed here
        });
        lastValueFrom(x1$);//comment this and no values will be printed
        console.log("===End===");
    }
}

let lvfe: LastValueFromExample = new LastValueFromExample();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop with your Observable.
Whenever `x1$` is subscribed to, you subscribe to it again, because the callback within the Observable constructor is called which itself includes a subscribe function.

The reason why nothing happens when you comment out `lastValueFrom(x1$)` is because `lastValueFrom(x1$)` subscribes to the observable, but never completes because x1$ never completes.

---

Edit: You could complete the observable within the constructor using:

```
  channel.complete();
```

---

If you want to see values as they occur, I'd recommend to use the [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator.

```js
const {
  from,
  of ,
  Observable,
  lastValueFrom,
  tap
} = rxjs;



class LastValueFromExample {
  constructor() {
    let x1$;
    console.log("===Start===");
    let i = 0;
    x1$ = new Observable((channel) => {
      i++;
      channel.next(Math.random());
    }).pipe(tap({
      next: (x) => {
        console.log(`${i} value: ${x}`)
      },
      // Note: this never runs.
      complete: (x) => {
        console.log(`Subscription completed with ${x}`)
      }
    }));
    // First subscription
    x1$.subscribe(); //subscribed here
    // Second subscription
    lastValueFrom(x1$); //comment this and no values will be printed
    console.log("===End===");
  }
}

let lvfe = new LastValueFromExample();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-f9/zRLfT4GaHBAniWJeFTsViOGP3hBxfEhecIauTbM5Ad51sTb4AoFJV5VbFl+Q7PClIU4kNHInGwhWFZKqE9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :). Can I please ask why `complete` will not run?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily as mentioned in the edit, you'd have to call 'channel.complete()` to get it to complete.